# Calculate fastest sum of field with where linq of datacontext

Tags: c#, linq, sum

I wanna transform my code:

```
using (DatabaseDataContext contestoDB = new DatabaseDataContext())
{
    contestoDB.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;

    DateTime dataSelezionata = DateTime.Parse(data);

    var elencoOre = (from db in contestoDB.Eventi
        where db.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSelezionata.Date select db);

    foreach (var o in elencoOre)
        oreOccupate += o.OrePreviste;
}
```

In this similar function for obtain sum of field with where :D :

```
var sum = contestoDB.Eventi.Sum(x => x.OrePreviste);
```

sum must be a int value...
Thanks
M.W.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see below:

```
var sum = contestoDB.Eventi
    .Where(w => w.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSelezionata.Date)
    .Sum(x => x.OrePreviste);
```

Comment: I have don it but not work :( int oreOccupate = Convert.ToInt32(contestoDB.Eventi
                             .Where(w => w.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSelezionata.Date)
                             .Sum(x => x.OrePreviste)); if null crash... :(

Comment: ok i've resolved with this : oreOccupate = contestoDB.Eventi.AsQueryable()
                        .Where(w => w.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSel.Date)
                        .Sum(x => (int?)x.OrePreviste) ?? 0; thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

You could just make a projection and take the sum of the projected values.

```
var sum = (from db in contestoDB.Eventi
    where db.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSelezionata.Date
    select db.OrePreviste).Sum();
```

or equivalently try this:

```
var sum =  contestoDB.Eventi
    .Where(evt => evt.DataPrenotazione.Date == dataSelezionata.Date)
    .Sum(evt => evt.OrePreviste);
```